# Why did a Java program keeps running even if I delete the executable .jar?

Tags: java, jar

I would like to know why this happens and wether this will always continues to happen when I delete a .jar file.
This behavior would speed my updates to new .jars. I will be able to replace the .jar with a new one and restart the application right away.

I am always using linux to deploy my applications.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Deleting a file won't stop an existing process from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux does not completely delete the file as long as it is still used by a process. It will only disappear completely when the last user terminates or closes the file.